# Sum of four Squares relation

Tags: number-theory, analytic-number-theory, sums-of-squares

Cheers,

As is well known due to Lagrange the number of ways to write $n$ as a sum of four squares is given by
$$
r_4(n)=8\sum_{d|n} d
$$ if $n$ is **odd**.

Now define $$
\tilde{r}_4(n)=\#\left\{1 + \sum_{i=1}^{4} n_i(n_i+1) = n \,\Big|\, (n_1,n_2,n_3,n_4) \in {\mathbb Z}^4 \right\}
$$
and clearly only for odd $n$ is $\tilde{r}_4(n)>0$ since $n_i(n_i+1)$ is even.

I'm trying to show that $$\tilde{r}_4(n)=2\,r_4(n)$$
for odd $n$, but I lack a clever idea :-(

**Background:** This problem arises if one tries to proof
$$\theta_2(0;q)^4 - \theta_3(0;q)^4 + \theta_4(0;q)^4 = 0$$
where $\theta_i(0;q)$ is the Jacobi Theta function. So maybe there is another way to proof this identity from which the original question then follows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$1+\sum_{k=1}^{4}n_k(n_k+1)=n$ is equivalent to

$$\sum_{k=1}^{4}(2n_k+1)^2 = 4n $$
so $\tilde{r}_4(n)$ accounts for the number of ways for writing $4n$ as the sum of four *odd* squares.
 On the other hand $a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2 = 4n$ implies that $a,b,c,d$ have the same parity, hence
$$\tilde{r}_4(n) = r_4(4n)-r_4(n) =2\,r_4(n).$$

Comment: Nice elegant way to solve it. Thanks so much!

Comment: +1 for simplest proof of the theta function identity.